# Java: De-Serialize a container of generic serializables?

Tags: java, serialization

I have different kinds of serializable `ObjectState`'s that store state data for important application objects. I do this so I can persist these important objects arcoss application instatances. The user will sometimes need to group certain objects together into containers, so some of the `ObjectState`'s are placed into an array of `ObjectState`'s and passed to a `ContainerState` (just a serializable class that holds an array of generic types serializables).

My question is, how do I de-serialize the `ContianerState` and keep type integrity? I thought I could try something like:

```
public static ContainerState<V> inflateState(V v, Serializable state) throws ClassCastException {
    return (ContainerState<V>)state;
}
```

But that won't even get past Eclipses' warning system. I also tried `V.class` to the same result. Is it even possible for me to achieve this?

EDIT 1:

I tried this, it seems to work, but I'm not sure if it's the best way. Any thoughts?

```
public static <cls extends Serializable> ContainerState<cls> inflateState(Class<? extends Serializable> cls, Serializable state) throws ClassCastException {
    return (ContainerState<cls>)state;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should at least compile:

```
public static <C extends Serializable> ContainerState<C> inflateState(Class<C> cls, Serializable state) throws ClassCastException {
    return (ContainerState<C>)state;
}
```

Comment: Hehe, thanks I figured it out. I came to the exact conclusion you did, just didn't answer my question (I'm a damn slacker :-P). Anywho credit is yours since I didn't post.